# How can I configure Hardhat to work with RSK regtest blockchain?

Tags: truffle, hardhat, rsk

I intend to develop my smart contracts in [Hardhat](https://hardhat.org/), and to test them on RSK regtest local node. I [was able to find](https://developers.rsk.co/tutorials/ethereum-devs/setup-truffle-oz/#configure-truffle-to-connect-to-rsk-regtest-local-node) a Truffle regtest configuration.

```
development: {
  host: "127.0.0.1",
  port: 4444,
  network_id: "*"
},
```

What `hardhat.config.js` configuration do I need to run my tests on RSK regtest?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To deploy and test your smart contracts on RSK regtest your`hardhat.config.js` should look as follows:

```js
/**
 * @type import('hardhat/config').HardhatUserConfig
 */
require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle");

module.exports = {
  solidity: "0.7.3",
  defaultNetwork: "rskregtest",
  networks: {
    rskregtest: {
      url: "http://localhost:4444/",
    },
  },
};
```

Then you'll be able to run your tests by typing in the terminal

```sh
% npx hardhat test
```